# Can't get ComboBox text to appear correctly

Tags: powershell, combobox

I have a script that will do the following:

Create a Form with 2 ComboBoxes and a Text Box for user entry
I populate ComboBox 1 and populate ComboBox 2 based on the selection from ComboBox 1. Another thing that partially works is I can get Text to appear on the form based on the selection of ComboBox 1.
My Challenges are challenges I have, by priority are:

Challenge 1:
How can I change the the text on the form doesn't update if I change the selection in ComboBox 1. selection in ComboBox 1?

Challenge 2: (linked to Challenge 1)
I am looking for a way to combing ComboBox 1 with ComboBox 2 with the Text Box
Example: Comp1-Tst-MyTst?

Challenge 3:
I'm looking to import a CSV file / OR using a Get-AD.... for the variables instead of hard coding in the script.

Challenge 4:
I'm struggling with adding an Icon to the form

Challenge 5:
I'd like to prevent the Ok Button from appearing until a Checkbox is checked

Here's the code I have:

```
# Below is one of the Array's I'm adding    
$ADSites=@("S01","S02","S03")

$ADSiteS01=@("AAA","BBB","CCC")
$ADSiteS02=@("DDD","EEE","FFF")
$ADSiteS03=@("GGG","HHH","JJJ")

####################################################################################################    
#####   Create Combo Boxes
####################################################################################################
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(625,625)
$Form.FormBorderStyle = "FixedToolWindow"
$Combobox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox
$Combobox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(26,25)  
$Combobox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(105,20)
$Combobox1.items.AddRange($ADSites)
$combobox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox
$combobox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(143,25)  
$combobox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(105,20)
$textBoxFPS = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$textBoxFPS.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(26,75) 
$textBoxFPS.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(165,20) 
$form.Controls.Add($textBoxFPS)
$Form.Controls.Add($combobox1)
$Form.Controls.Add($combobox2)

################################################################################################
#####   Create Text Box
################################################################################################
$textBoxFPS = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$textBoxFPS.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(26,75) 
$textBoxFPS.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(165,20) 
$form.Controls.Add($textBoxFPS)





################################################################################################
#####   Add Labels for the Combo Boxes
###################################################################################################

$lbADSub = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label   
$lbADSub.Text = "Select AD Site"; $lbADSub.Top = 5; $lbADSub.Left = 26; $lbADSub.Autosize = $true  
$form.Controls.Add($lbADSub)

$lbDeptSub = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label   
$lbDeptSub.Text = "Select Department"; $lbDeptSub.Top = 5; $lbDeptSub.Left = 143; 
$lbDeptSub.Autosize = $true  
$form.Controls.Add($lbDeptSub)  

$lbFPSSub = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label   
$lbFPSSub.Text = "Type in the Asset Tag"; $lbFPSSub.Top = 55; $lbFPSSub.Left = 26; 
$lbFPSSub.Autosize = $true
$form.Controls.Add($lbFPSSub) 

## CheckBox 
$chkThis = New-Object Windows.Forms.checkbox 
$chkThis.Text = "Verify New Computer Name" ; $chkThis.Left = 26; $chkThis.Top = 105; 
$chkThis.AutoSize = $true
$chkThis.Checked = $false   # set a default value 
$form.Controls.Add($chkThis) 


<#
$lbCompSub = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label   
$lbCompSub.Text = "Verify Computer Name"; $lbCompSub.Top = 105; $lbCompSub.Left = 26; 
$lbCompSub.Autosize = $true  
$form.Controls.Add($lbCompSub) 
#>


############################################################################################
#####   Create Ok and Cancel Buttons
############################################################################################

$buttonPanel = New-Object Windows.Forms.Panel
    $buttonPanel.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(400,40)
    $buttonPanel.Dock = "Bottom"

## Creating the Ok Button

    $okButton = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
        $okButton.Top = $cancelButton.Top ; $okButton.Left = $cancelButton.Left - $okButton.Width - 5
        $okButton.Text = "Ok" 
        $okButton.DialogResult = "Ok" 
        $okButton.Anchor = "Left" 

## Creating the Cancel Button
    $cancelButton = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
        $cancelButton.Left = $buttonPanel.Height - $cancelButton.Height - 10; $cancelButton.Left = $buttonPanel.Width - $cancelButton.Width - 10
        $cancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
        $cancelButton.DialogResult = "Cancel"
        $cancelButton.Anchor = "Right"

## Add the buttons to the button panel 
    $buttonPanel.Controls.Add($okButton) 
    $buttonPanel.Controls.Add($cancelButton) 
## Add the button panel to the form 
    $form.Controls.Add($buttonPanel) 
## Set Default actions for the buttons 
    $form.AcceptButton = $okButton          # ENTER = Ok 
    $form.CancelButton = $cancelButton      # ESCAPE = Cancel



##################################################################################################
#####   Now we do stuff
##################################################################################################

# Populate Combobox 2 When Combobox 1 changes
$ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged= {
    $combobox2.Items.Clear() # Clear the list
    $combobox2.Text = $null  # Clear the current entry
    Switch ($ComboBox1.Text) {
            "S01"{
            $ADSiteS01 | ForEach { 
                $labelClub = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
                $labelClub.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,200) 
                $labelClub.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
                $labelClub.Text = "$($combobox1.SelectedItem)-"
                $form.Controls.Add($labelClub)
                $combobox2.Items.Add($_)
                #$labelClub.Text = "$($combobox2.SelectedItem)-"
            }
        }
            "S02"{
            $ADSiteS02 | ForEach {
                $labelClub = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
                $labelClub.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,200) 
                $labelClub.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
                $labelClub.Text = "$($combobox1.SelectedItem)-"
                $form.Controls.Add($labelClub)
                $combobox2.Items.Add($_)
             }
        }
        "S03"{
            $ADSiteS03 | ForEach {
                $labelClub = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
                $labelClub.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,200) 
                $labelClub.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
                $labelClub.Text = "$($combobox1.SelectedItem)-"
                $form.Controls.Add($labelClub)
                $combobox2.Items.Add($_)
              }
        }

       }
}

$ComboBox1.add_SelectedIndexChanged($ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged)
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: We are here to assist with where you are having code that is not working/failing, but your question is really asking us to train you on how to design a GUI for your use case, as defined by each of your challenges. GUI design is GUI design, PowerShell notwithstanding. So, you sould really spend the time learning GUI desing first. There are lots of tools to help. Hit youtube, and search for 'powershell windows forms gui design' GUI. You'll get a lot of work thru.

Comment: I guess I should not have asked all of the problems since I'm not looking to be trained. If you note, I can create the GUI, I can add and control the information on the first two Combo Boxes with the exception of getting them to properly update and populate the text in the form. I've looked in multiple books and locations and the only place I found that came close was here on Stack Overflow however. Based on many of the questions I've seen on here I thought this was a forum where I am able to ask a question and seek help. Is that the case or should I look elsewhere?

Comment: You can ask a question and seek help on Stack Overflow, however it is _not_ a forum; it's more Q&A-focused than that.  The general rule of thumb is "One question per question", but you have essentially asked *5*.  #1 and #2 could maybe be one question since they are related.  Definitely #3 and probably #4 and #5 should be their own questions.  Also, if you merely split this laundry ("challenge") list into individual questions without more details/research effort, they're likely to be downvoted.  As much text as you've provided for _5_ questions you really should be giving for _each_ question.

Comment: @BACON, I appreciate your responses and can adjust moving forward. As an Instructor and a Mentor on other aspects of the IT world, I try to help guide people on the right / wrong ways of doing something. Given that this is my first posting and the first time I was unable to find the information I needed in my existing material, I'm glad that you both took the time to help me understand this forum. We ALL started as Noob's and it's by helping each other we help others as well as ourselves. Again, I'll do better moving forward.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should help you out on the combo box issue and the OK button:

```
# Below is one of the Array's I'm adding    
$ADSites=@("S01","S02","S03")

$ADSiteS01=@("AAA","BBB","CCC")
$ADSiteS02=@("DDD","EEE","FFF")
$ADSiteS03=@("GGG","HHH","JJJ")


Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
#
####################################################################################################    
#####   Create Combo Boxes
####################################################################################################
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Size = '625,625'
$Form.FormBorderStyle = "FixedToolWindow"
#
$Combobox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox
$Combobox1.Location = '26,25'
$Combobox1.Size = '105,20'
$Combobox1.items.AddRange($ADSites)
#
$combobox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox
$combobox2.Location = '143,25'
$combobox2.Size = '105,20'
#
#
$Form.Controls.Add($combobox1)
$Form.Controls.Add($combobox2)

################################################################################################
#####   Create Text Box
################################################################################################
$textBoxFPS = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$textBoxFPS.Location = '26,75'
$textBoxFPS.Size = '165,20'
$textBoxFPS.Text = 'xx'
$form.Controls.Add($textBoxFPS)





################################################################################################
#####   Add Labels for the Combo Boxes
###################################################################################################

$lbADSub = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label   
$lbADSub.Text = "Select AD Site"; $lbADSub.Top = 5; $lbADSub.Left = 26; $lbADSub.Autosize = $true  
$form.Controls.Add($lbADSub)

$lbDeptSub = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label   
$lbDeptSub.Text = "Select Department"; $lbDeptSub.Top = 5; $lbDeptSub.Left = 143; 
$lbDeptSub.Autosize = $true  
$form.Controls.Add($lbDeptSub)  

$lbFPSSub = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label   
$lbFPSSub.Text = "Type in the Asset Tag"; $lbFPSSub.Top = 55; $lbFPSSub.Left = 26; 
$lbFPSSub.Autosize = $true
$form.Controls.Add($lbFPSSub) 

## CheckBox 
$chkThis = New-Object Windows.Forms.checkbox 
$chkThis.Text = "Verify New Computer Name" ; $chkThis.Left = 26; $chkThis.Top = 105; 
$chkThis.AutoSize = $true
$chkThis.Checked = $false   # set a default value 
$form.Controls.Add($chkThis) 

############################
# Label for choice selection
############################
$labelClub = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$labelClub.Location = '20,200'
$labelClub.Size = '280,20'
$labelClub.Text = "-"
$form.Controls.Add($labelClub)



<#
$lbCompSub = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label   
$lbCompSub.Text = "Verify Computer Name"; $lbCompSub.Top = 105; $lbCompSub.Left = 26; 
$lbCompSub.Autosize = $true  
$form.Controls.Add($lbCompSub) 
#>


############################################################################################
#####   Create Ok and Cancel Buttons
############################################################################################

$buttonPanel = New-Object Windows.Forms.Panel
    $buttonPanel.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(400,40)
    $buttonPanel.Dock = "Bottom"

## Creating the Ok Button

    $okButton = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
        $okButton.Top = $cancelButton.Top ; $okButton.Left = $cancelButton.Left - $okButton.Width - 5
        $okButton.Text = "Ok" 
        $okButton.DialogResult = "Ok" 
        $okButton.Anchor = "Left" 
        $okButton.Enabled = $false

## Creating the Cancel Button
    $cancelButton = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
        $cancelButton.Left = $buttonPanel.Height - $cancelButton.Height - 10; $cancelButton.Left = $buttonPanel.Width - $cancelButton.Width - 10
        $cancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
        $cancelButton.DialogResult = "Cancel"
        $cancelButton.Anchor = "Right"

## Add the buttons to the button panel 
    $buttonPanel.Controls.Add($okButton) 
    $buttonPanel.Controls.Add($cancelButton) 
## Add the button panel to the form 
    $form.Controls.Add($buttonPanel) 
## Set Default actions for the buttons 
    $form.AcceptButton = $okButton          # ENTER = Ok 
    $form.CancelButton = $cancelButton      # ESCAPE = Cancel



##################################################################################################
#####   Now we do stuff
##################################################################################################

# Populate Combobox 2 When Combobox 1 changes
$ComboBox1.add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    $combobox2.Items.Clear() # Clear the list
    $combobox2.Text = $null  # Clear the current entry
    Switch ($ComboBox1.Text) {
            "S01"{

            $ADSiteS01 | ForEach { 
                $combobox2.Items.Add($_)
            }
        }
            "S02"{
            $ADSiteS02 | ForEach {
                $combobox2.Items.Add($_)
             }
        }
        "S03"{
            $ADSiteS03 | ForEach {
                $combobox2.Items.Add($_)
              }
        }

    }
    $labelClub.Text = $combobox1.Text + "-" + $combobox2.Text + "-" + $textBoxFPS.Text
})

$ComboBox2.add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    $labelClub.Text = $combobox1.Text + "-" + $combobox2.Text + "-" + $textBoxFPS.Text
})

$textBoxFPS.add_TextChanged({
    $labelClub.Text = $combobox1.Text + "-" + $combobox2.Text + "-" + $textBoxFPS.Text
})

$chkThis.Add_CheckStateChanged({
   If ($chkThis.Checked) {
       $okButton.enabled = $true
   }
   Else {
    $okButton.enabled = $false
   }
})

$Form.ShowDialog()
```

- If you use an AD cmdlet to retrieve site details into an object you should easily be able to populate lists from that object using the same method you have now.

Comment: Yes, that works. I did change the $okButton.enabled =$false to $okButton.enabled =$true and it appears (greyed out) until the checkbox is checked. with it set to $false, nothing the OK didn't show up. 
Thank you for helping me with get past the blocker...

Comment: Er, how can this be the accepted answer when it addresses, at most, 2 or 3 of the issues raised in the question?  This is the problem with a question that covers so many different points.  Also, it would be helpful if this answer either explained what it's doing and/or trimmed the code down to just the parts that were changed.  The reader shouldn't be forced to diff this with the original code nor just copy-and-paste and hope it works.

Comment: Actually, the proposed solution presented by Scepticalist gave me all the information I needed to get the rest of the pieces put together.

Challenge 1: Resolved with the proposed solution

Challenge 2: Resolved with the proposed solution

Challenge 3: I'm incorporating this in the script delivery since it needs the AD environment

Challenge 4: I'm struggling with adding an Icon to the form
This has been put on the back burner

Challenge 5: Resolved....
Once I have the final, if you would like, I can post the final script with comments. Besides, this was not a request for training

Comment: Adding an icon is a whole subject in itself - best to post a separate question if you go down that road.

Comment: I've solved the issue of the image and was planning on uploading the final script once completed.